# Application of Landau's theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> **Landau's theorem:** For each positive integer $k$ there exists a bound $B(k)$, such that a finite group having exactly $k$ conjugacy classes satisfies $|G| < B(K)$.

Can someone tell me some applications of this theorem?